# How do I print all corresponding elements of 2 lists and separate them by text?

Tags: python

I wish to create a program in Python that prompts the user to enter a number of integer values. The
program stores the integers, counts the frequency of each integer and displays the frequency
as per the below image.

[image]

I have the following code but I don't know how to execute the final step (i.e. print "1 occurs 2 times" and below that "2 occurs 3 times" etc)

```
selection = int(input("Input the number of elements to be stored in the list: "))          

counter = 1
valuesList = []

while counter <= selection:
    value = input("Element - " + str(counter) + ": ")
    valuesList.append(value)
    counter +=1

#count number occurrences of each value
import collections
counter=collections.Counter(valuesList)

#create a list for the values occurring and a list for the corresponding frequencies 
keys = counter.keys()
values2 = counter.values()

print("The frequency of all elements in the list: ")
```

Below the last print should be a series of print commands: keys[0] + "occurs" + values2[0] + "times" and continue for the all values within 'keys'. But I don't know how to print for all values in the list if the length of the list changes depending on the original 'selection' input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is a compact solution for what you need using list comprehension and the count function of lists

```py
print('The frequency of all elements of the list :')
print('\n'.join({f'{i} occurs {valuesList.count(i)} times' for i in valuesList}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools library. This should work for you.

```
import itertools

print("The frequency of all elements in the list: ")
for key, vals in itertools.zip_longest(keys, values2):
    print("{0} occurs {1} times".format(key, vals))
```